# How to dynamically update series data and legend in SWTChart?

Tags: eclipse, swtchart

I'm working on a project using SWTChart in Eclipse, and I need to update the series data and legend dynamically based on user selection.

#### Problem

I've created a chart using SWTChart, and I want to update the series data and legend when the user makes a specific selection. Here's a snippet of my current code:

How can I dynamically update the series data and legend in SWTChart based on user selection? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciate

```
private void createMiniLineChart(Chart lineChart, double[] seriesdata, String graphID) {

    // set titles
    lineChart.getTitle().setText(EZPDContants.EMPTY_STRING);
    lineChart.getAxisSet().getXAxis(0).getTitle().setVisible(false);
    lineChart.getAxisSet().getYAxis(0).getTitle().setVisible(false);
    ISeries series = (ILineSeries<?>) lineChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, graphID);
    series.setXSeries(seriesdata);
    // adjust the axis range
    lineChart.getAxisSet().adjustRange();

    // hide the x and y axis
    lineChart.getAxisSet().getXAxis(0).getTick().setVisible(false);
    lineChart.getAxisSet().getYAxis(0).getTick().setVisible(false);
    //Hide the default legend provided by SWTChart.
    lineChart.getLegend().setVisible(false);
    
    // Set the chart layout data
    lineChart.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    
     // Draw the border
    lineChart.setForeground(lineChart.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
    lineChart.setBackground(lineChart.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    lineChart.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    
    lineChart.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
              System.out.println("Mouse double-clicked!");
              refreshGraphTemp();
            System.out.println(seriesdata);
        }
    });
    

    createCustomLegend(lineChart.getParent(), graphID);
    // Set the chart redraw flag
    lineChart.setRedraw(true);

}


private void     refreshGraphTemp() {
    //lineChart.getSeriesSet().clear();
    series.setXSeries(seriesMaindata);
    //cleare legend 
   //lineChart.getLegend().

    lineChart.getAxisSet().adjustRange();
    lineChart.setRedraw(true);
}
```